# Store vector values (x,y,z) in a matrix in a for loop. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I wanted to create a matrix (A) that is flexible on size depending on how many data are available in a for loop. My code goes like this.

```
%Calculate x,y,z values
for i = 1:100
Vx = equation that will solve x values;
Vy = equation that will solve y values;
Vz = equation that will solve z values;
A = [Vx, Vy, Vz];  
end
```

I would like matrix A to have a size of nx3, where n is any number of rows arrived by the calculation of x y z. In other words at after the for loop I would like to have matrix A with size n x 3.

Comment: So are `Vx, Vy, Vz` scalars? Are they matrices with same number of rows/columns? Or are they matrices with all three of them having different number of rows/columns? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes, Vx Vy and Vz are scalars. in fact they are coordinates of a point.

Comment: Then just do: `A(i,:) = [Vx, Vy, Vz]`, assuming in every iteration of for loop you generate a `1x3` vector of `[Vx,Vy,Vz]`.